# Serie Fibonacci modificada

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente enunciado: 
Escribe un programa que imprime la serie Fibonacci hasta el número n de la serie. Por
ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa 7, el programa retorna: 1, 1, 2, 6, 9, 17, 31.
 = −3 + −2 + −3

Para lo cual he hecho varios intentos pero en realidad no se me sale la serie que dice el enunciado, este es un poco del codigo que he hecho

```
public static Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=1;
    int b=1;
    int c=2;
    int d;
     //  1, 1, 2, 6, 9, 17, 31. 
    for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++) {
        d=a+b+c;
        System.out.println(d+"\t");
        a=b;
        b=c;
        c=d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Me parece no existe una comprensión de la serie de Fibonacci. La serie suma el número anterior al número actual... Así, desde 1 es

1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21......

Comment: justamente por eso puse "serie fibonacci modificada", este enunciado no usa el esquema comun de la serie fibonacci

Comment: Gracias por la corrección, Jose.

Comment: y tambien al estar modificada, es la principal razon por la que no he podido realizar este enunciado, como lo dije, he intentado de varias formas ya pero en ninguna obtengo el resultado que se espera, o al menos en su mayoria

Comment: ¿La formula que pusiste es correcta? no le encuentro mucho sentido, ¿podrías expresarla de mejor forma?

Comment: mira es que ese enunciado que puse, pertenece a un taller que nos dejo el profesor, asi que yo tampoco sabria explicarlo, pero si, estoy empezando a creer que esta mal planteado el punto

Comment: Tienes la formula en forma Algebraica?, es decir en tipo sumatoria, seria un poco más fácil, sino tendríamos que deducirla por inducción matemática.

Comment: no, asi tal cual me enviaron el ejercicio y pues que la serie debia cumplir esto  = −3 + −2 + −3

Comment: ¿sabes que significa NT?